# Error on fingerPrint scanning in Google Pixel

Tags: android

I am using FingerPrint unlocking API in application.
I got following crash log but unable to reproduce this issue. Anyone have idea what is wrong here

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'int java.util.List.size()' on a null object reference
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1948)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
at android.hardware.fingerprint.IFingerprintService$Stub$Proxy.authenticate(IFingerprintService.java:323)
at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.authenticate(FingerprintManager.java:431)
at android.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManager.authenticate(FingerprintManager.java:389)
at android.support.v4.hardware.fingerprint.FingerprintManagerCompat.authenticate(FingerprintManagerCompat.java:113)
```

Comment: `List.size()` is empty and i believe you are using `RecyclerView` or sth which is null. Check your items.

Comment: @AbdulKawee Please check updated explanation.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท No I am not using any RecyclerView or ListView. This is not UI crash. It is coming from IFingerprintService .

Comment: @ManishKumawat Did you find any solution? I have seen this crash as well

Comment: I'm also seeing this crash in a Motorola Moto G (5) Plus. Any update?

Comment: I also encountered this on LG V40 ThinQ running 8.0

Comment: Is there any update on this issue? Got the same problem on a BQ Aquaris X